# how to use ruby/rails to convert all caps to proper first letter cap, rest lower case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a data file of names and address...all of them are upper case.

How can I convert it to properly make the first letter upper case, and the rest lower case (except for states, for example)?

I could probably isolate the states to not go through the parse, but for the rest, how could I do this for a ruby on rails application?

Comment: Please remember that this isn't a reasonable thing to do unless you also have culture information for each name (and that's very, very unlikely).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you can separate the states out, like you say, it's easy:

```
my_address_string.titlecase
```

It'll capitalize the first letter of every word (including some I'd rather it didn't, like "a" or "the", but hey...) and uncapitalize the rest.  Sounds just like what you want.

Comment: @Angela  Really?  That's odd...  What version of Rails are you running?  Also - does it work in script/console?  For me, running something generic like `"TEST PHRASE".titlecase` in script/console works perfectly...

Comment: I gave this answer the points for getting me in the right direction, but titelize is what ended up working....thanks

Comment: @Angela  That's so weird.  `titlecase` is just an alias for `titleize` - they should be exactly the same function (and I'm on 2.3.8 too)!  Glad I could be of some help, at least.  Cheers!

Comment: Bear in mind that titleize/titlecase will make some little modifications when it feels to do so. For example, "x-men: the last stand".titleize  # => "X Men: The Last Stand". See the documentation: http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M000381

Answer (score 1):

Xavier's answer is working for me in Rails 2.3.5 environment. Or you can try this

```
my_address_string.downcase.gsub(/(\A|\s)\w/){ |letter| letter.upcase }
```

Comment: my_address_string.downcase.gsub(/(\A|\s)\w/){ |letter| letter.upcase }

Answer (score 0):

I made a gem to take care of this issue called [address_titlecase](https://github.com/juliannaroen/address_titlecase). It should work for US and Canadian addresses.